# There is a way to call hooks conditionally in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a different hook according to a variable... this value comes from URL parameters and is dynamic, but hooks can't run conditionally according to Hook's rules:

### Example

```js
// this hook comes from react-router dom to get the URL params
const param = const { productType, accountId, statementId } = useParams();

// I need to run a hook that calls a different API according productType value
if (productType === 'someType') {
  return useHookOne(accountId, statementId)
} else if (productType === 'otherType') {
  return useHookTwo(accountId, statementId)
} else {
  return useHookThree(accountId, statementId)
}
```

Comment: sounds like you need different components for different product types.

Comment: Conditionally render a component that calls the hook. But you can't conditionally call the hook *within* a component.

Comment: @Cristian Florez you might be able to get away with this by creating your own custom hook, and applying the logic within the hooks conditionally. Can you clarify if each hook is similar but with different values, or are they entirely different hooks (with different functionality)?

Comment: @Urmzd are the same hooks with the difference that calls a different APIs... one hook for every product type detail endpoint...

Comment: @CristianFlórez is there a reason for the hook? Is it wired to some provider or contains some internal state you must manage? Or are you simply trying to have a hook with supports difference api calls?

Comment: each hook is a wrapper of useQuery method from react query, which is in charge of calling the different APIs...

Answer (score 6):

You need to create 3 others components for each scenario. In each component, you can add his own logic.

```
const param = const { productType, accountId, statementId } = useParams();

// I need to run a hook that calls a different API according productType value
if (productType === 'someType') {
  return <UseHookOne accountId={accountId} statementId={statementId} />
} else if (productType === 'otherType') {
  return <UseHookTwo accountId={accountId} statementId={statementId} />
} else {
  return <UseHookThree accountId={accountId} statementId={statementId} />
}
```

And then create 3 new components. Example with `UseHookOne`

```
import React from 'react'

const UseHookOne = (props) => {
  const data = useHookOne(props.accountId, props.statementId)
  return (<>Yay! Logic number 1 based on {data}</>)
}
export default UseHookOne
```

Comment: I'm going to expose the specific scenario, the products are banking products: credit cards, checking and saving accounts, and other ones... there are different endpoints for every product type, the data returned by the endpoints is the same, so according to this why do I need three components to print the same data?... the unique function of the component would be being a wrapper to call a specific hook... there is another approach?

Comment: If you have to call 3 different endpoints, you must have 3 different logic. If the response of the API is similar (it's a separate problem), use a shared component that will be called within all the 3 other components

Answer (score 1):

**Hooks can't be called into function or conditions**

Use hook in the root and put condition for each Hook.

Can you predict the purpose of your code? I think the logical design of the code should just be approached from a different angle

EDIT with Exemple:

```js
// this hook comes from react-router dom to get the URL params
const param = const { productType, accountId, statementId } = useParams();

let apiRequest = new productRequestAPI();

if(prodType == "firstType"){
 apiQuest.adress = 'adress.api.com';
apiQuest.quest: 'firstRequest';
apiQuest.accountId ... etc
}
else if(prodType == "secondType"){
...
}

singleHook(apiRequest){
//Call API with good params and return after

}
```

Comment: The idea is to get the `productType` value that comes from URL, and call and endpoint that brings product detail, this endpoint is different for every productType.

Comment: You can create for each one a component. I think it's the best simplicity / efficiency ratio

Comment: I'm going to expose the specific scenario, the products are banking products: credit cards, checking and saving accounts, and other ones... there are different endpoints for every product type, the data returned by the endpoints is the same, so according to this why do I need three components to print the same data?... the unique function of the component would be being a wrapper to call a specific hook... there is another approach?

Comment: You can manage everything in a single Hook and manage the logic inside if I understood your problem correctly.
At the end you call a method that puts everything in good shape.

Another option is to change the input data of your Hook, this may be sufficient especially if the output is "identical" on all your products.

Comment: Can you update your answer with an example for every scenario please... I don't get your point...

Comment: @CristianFlórez, it's done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239380/discussion-between-menofre-and-cristian-florez).

Answer (score 0):

```
    useHookOne('x', 'y', prodType === "firstType")
    useHookTwo('x', 'y', prodType === "secondType")
    useHookOne('x', 'y', prodType === "thirdType"
    
    
    
    const useHookOne = (a,b,enabled)=> {
      if (!enabled) return;
     // Write core logic below

    }

    const useHookTwo = (a,b,enabled)=> {
      if (!enabled) return;
     // Write core logic below

    }
   
    const useHookThree = (a,b,enabled)=> {
      if (!enabled) return;
     // Write core logic below

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make the useHookOne return a function that takes two arguments accountId and statementId .

```
const setHookOne = useHookOne()
const setHookTwo = useHookTwo()
const setHookThree = useHookThree()

if (productType === 'someType') {
  return setHookOne(accountId, statementId)
}else if (productType === 'otherType') {
  return setHookTwo(accountId, statementId)
} else {
  return setHookThree(accountId, statementId)
}
```